# Arranging a list of values randomly

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I would like to arrange a list of values randomly with a **formula** automatically.
My data has repetitive values.

Sample data in columns A:E

```
    Data
    4   6   8   0   0
    1   5   5   7   9
```

So when randomized, in columns I:M, it would look something like this:

```
Randomized Data             
6   0   8   4   0
5   1   7   5   9
```

I tried something with rand and randbetween, and found a formula but it doesn't work repetitive numbers. Can I get any suggestion please? thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no Ms365? Would be easy then.

Comment: yes, unfortunately I have Excel 2016.

Comment: Easy enough with a user-defined VBA function. In any event -- what is the formula that you tried? The solution might lie in a tweak to your best effort.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. this is the formula: =AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$2:$E$2/(COUNTIF($h2:h2,$A$2:$E$2)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,COLUMNS(i2:$M2)))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `RAND`, `RANK` and `INDEX`:

[image]

The strategy is to create a vector of random numbers, calculate their rank, and then use this rank to read off the columns on the data set.

In the above screenshot I used:

```
=RANK(A4,$A$4:$E$4)
```

in `A5`,

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$2,1,A6)
```

in `A8`, and

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$2,2,A6)
```

in `A9`.

It might be possible to get this down to a single array formula, though the result then wouldn't be very readable.

Comment: thanks, this might work, but I'd like to avoid using helper cells really if possible.